# How can I get a HTML output instead of markdown?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm currently using [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/) to have a text editor inside my app (made with nextjs). Thing is, I would like my editor output to be HTML instead of markdown.

current editor code

```
<CKEditor
  // @ts-ignore
  editor={CKEditorCustomBuild}
  onChange={(event: any, editor: any) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    onChange(data);
  }}
/>
```

The output of `data` inside of the `onChange` function would be something like:

```markdown
Hello there, my _name_ is **John Doe**.
```

And I would like to have the following format:

```html
Hello there, my <u>name</u> is <strong>John Doe</strong>.
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: CKEditor 5 by default outputs content in HTML format. If you're getting Markdown as the output, it's possible that you're using a Markdown plugin or a custom build that's configured to output Markdown.

Comment: You were totally right, the build of CKEditor that my team provided had a markdown output plugin in it. Thanks a lot for your help! Could you add this as a response in order for me to actually give you the right answer?

Comment: answer posted just now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per discussion in comments with @endbermudas:

CKEditor 5 by default outputs content in HTML format. If you're getting Markdown as the output, it's possible that you're using a Markdown plugin or a custom build that's configured to output Markdown.